# ASP.NET MVC Routing construct links based on current url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have urls that look like this

`~\articles\energy\topweek`

`~\articles\metals\latestpopular`

where second url string is a category and third is a filter

so route looks like this

```
    routes.MapRoute("ArticleFilter",
     "articles/{category}/{filter}",
  new { controller="Article", action="Filter" })
```

That's pretty easy and everything works fine.

So lets say if i'm looking at articles{category}\ default view.

How do I construct links to point to current category with filters.

Example: 
If current page `articles\energy`, I need to construct `article\energy\topweek` and `article\energy\latestpopular`.

Where category should be dynamic based on the current page. 
preferably in a partial view so I can use it across different pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object for your usercontrol to take as model like this :

```
public class ArticleLinksControl {
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

And your user control : 
`<%@ Control Language="C#" 
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Namespace.ArticleLinksControl>" %>`

Assuming your view for the ArticleController's default action also accepts a model that holds the information about the category name, you can send the category name to your user control this way :

```
<%Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/YourControl.ascx",
    new NameSpace.ArticleLinksControl { 
        CategoryName = Model.Category}); %>
```

Now in your usercontrol you can access the category name with `Model.CategoryName`.

This is if you insist on using a usercontrol for this. You can also get away with using Html helpers on your view.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `UrlHelper` class to construct the route url's, after splitting the url strings to get the information you need.

```
string url = "~\articles\film\topweek";
string[] parts = url.Split("\\");
string cat = parts[2];
string fil = parts[3];

string actionUrl = UrlHelper.RouteUrl("ActionFilter", new { category = cat, filter = fil });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Html.RouteLink (or Html.ActionLink) to build the URL.

```
<% Html.RouteLink('link text', routeName, new { filter = "topweek" }) %>
```